# Drawing a list tree in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, tree

I am trying to draw a tree that, but i can't find a way so that the "branches" don't overlap. I need somone that did this before to give a brilliant idea. I tried a few methods that didn't work (or i used them poorly), so i'm open to any suggestion.

This is the code i'm using to draw the tree :

```
public void drawNode(Graphics g, Node node, float x, float y)
            {
                Font sFont = new Font("Helvetica",13);
                if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, y, x, y + 20);
                    g.DrawString(node.litera.ToString(), sFont, Brushes.Blue, x, y + 25);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (node.Left != null)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, y, x - 20, y + 20);
                        drawNode(g, node.Left, x - 20, y + 20);

                    }
                    if (node.Right != null)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, y, x + 20, y + 20);
                        drawNode(g, node.Right, x + 20, y + 20);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Everything is drawn correctly, except the overlap problem.

Comment: `I need somone that did this before to give a brilliant idea` - A brilliant idea would be to use a current (< 10 years old) UI framework, such as WPF or WinRT.